# Finding the correct word for something which is optional and can be empty

Tags: adjectives

I was actually writing a program but couldn't find the suitable word

I write `Breakable` for `something that can be broken`

```
    Nullable --> Something that can be null
    Callable --> Someone who can be called
    Runnable --> Something that can run
    Walkable --> A place that is at near distance and be walked
```

What should be the similar kind word for --> `"something which can empty"` ?

#### Edit :-

In my program handles validation of some properties like below

```
// Lets say that a person does not have middle name, 
// For these kind of properties they have created a Notation @Nullable, 
 // which is placed on the top of property name.

@Nullable
private String middleName;
```

Similarly consider another example of a travel user preferences file created by a online service. Only few preferences optional .

In that case developers has created a @Ignorable Notation to denote that wifi is preferable but apartment must have water and laptop charger

```
NeedWater
NeedCharger

@Ignorable 
NeedWifi
```

Since all these are using a sinlge word I wanted to create a notation to denote a Box of goods which can be empty.

```
@Emptyable
GoodsBox
```

In this case `@Nullable` is not valid for me as That would mean my box does not exist.

Comment: Why not just use "emptyable"? After all, "nullable" isn't really a word (at least according to many reputable sources), so if you're willing to use unwordables . . .

Comment: Thanks I though that too, I will use this, I had optional in my mind too, but its was not matching the other words.

Comment: "emptyable" means ***capable of being emptied***. But lots of "empty" things (an empty promise or laugh, empty space,...) can't be emptied - they just ***are*** empty.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - ***capable of being [verbed]*** applies to all four words in the list.  If a variable *is null* it's because it was assigned that value (i.e. nulled).  No need for a digression into initialized states - if it was initialized as null it was *assigned* null (i.e. nulled).

Comment: @EllieK: I never took exception to those four examples. But to my mind, *NOUN is capable of being VERBed* normally implies it's possible to perform some action causing NOUN to change from "Not VERBed" to "VERBed". Suppose I define some "converging" mathematical sequence (1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5...). Even if I don't actually *know* the sum of the series, I know for sure it has some *fixed* value. Which to my mind implies I *cant* say *The sum of the series is capable of being zero*  because it either is or it isn't. And I *certainly* can't say that sum is capable of being ***zeroised***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes, I think I agree.  My point was the rules that apply to *emptiable* also apply to *nullable* and the other words.  Just because something *is* null, for example, does not necessarily mean it's *nullable*.  It may just be null and its state may be fixed.

Comment: As I rather suspected, the word you want is part of the code, and not written in English.  This means that the "rules" of English don't apply.  For example the "ignoreable" would be very odd in English.  You don't say to a clerk "I need wifi but that requirement is ignoreable"

Comment: In programming languges, "emptiable" is the default state.  So I'd suggest a marker `@nonempty` to mark containers that must contain at least one item.

Comment: But I want the reverse of @nonempty.  Also The code is not written in pure English, but I wanted to stay more close to English as much as I can

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing the comments:

```
 //This set may be empty.
```

is better than "//This set is emptiable" or any other adjective.

Comment: And if you are writing code, that is not natural English, and you need to follow the rules of the programming language, its not a good question for this stack.  In the computer languages that I know, there is no need for such a term, as all data structures with indefinite length (lists, sets, hashes...) may be empty by default.  You would only need a term if the structure may not be empty.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for a single word, if any exist.

Comment: Why do you want a single word.  Can you give an example sentence in your question?

Comment: :- I have updated my question as you suggested